# How does PHP access information about the client's browser?

Tags: php

How is it possible for client browser data to be saved in an array in PHP?

PHP runs on the server side, so I don't understand how it has access to information about the client's browser.

Comment: Which "client browser data" are you referring to?

Comment: browser name, version and etc...

Answer (score 1):

The client sends data to the server which the server uses to build the array (I'm assuming you're talking about `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`, etc.)

Comment: no when user requests a PHP page does it always send full browser information?? i dont think so, as this can result in more traffic

Comment: Ummm yes it does. HTTP is a stateless protocol. It has way of saving data between requests on its own. The only way PHP's interpreter can know in any given request who you are and what you previously did is if your browser sends the cookie payload and/or GET/POST variables that identify you by associating you with a PHP session.

Answer (score 1):

[User agent data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) is usually sent with every HTTP requests, in the `User-Agent` [HTTP header field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests). You might want to read up on [HTTP message formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_request#Request_message) in general. For example, this is part of the HTTP request that my browser sent to load jQuery on this very page:

```
GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 01 Apr 2011 21:23:55 GMT
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.60 Safari/534.24
Accept: */*
```

PHP reads the client browser data that you're asking about from the `User-Agent` header field.

Answer (score 1):

You will find it here

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

You may need to parse this by regex to get the browser name and version separately.

Answer (score 0):

[$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Answer (score 0):

The data is submited by the browser when a new page is requested, PHP just puts it into an array for your convenience.

You should start by reading a bit about HTTP (GET and POST to begin with), and HTTP headers.